# if statement batch was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch with this code:

```
set /p carga= ¿Carga inicial o carga diaria?

if "%carga%"=="c" (

    sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.SP_OFB_INF_PSN @VALOR = 1, @FECHA=''" -S (local) -d bd_ofb -o OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt

)
```

but i have this error

> -d was unexpected at this time

if I leave the outside of the `IF` there is no error code

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.SP_OFB_INF_PSN @VALOR = 1, @FECHA=''" -S (local) -d bd_ofb -o OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt
```

Comment: Try moving the -d before the -Q.

Comment: the `)` of `(local`) is falsely taken as closing `)` to the loop. You have to escape it: `...  -S (local^) -d ...`

Comment: There really isn't any reason to have the parentheses. Just remove them and put the `IF` command and your sql command all on one line.

Comment: @Squashman, technically I agree with you, but cosmetically the parentheses make sense in my opinion as they make the code more legible...

Comment: @aschipfl, I agree as well from readability.  99% of the time I write all my code with indentation and formatting that makes it very readable.  But this would be the 1% of the time that I would just put it on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the closing bracket (with `^)`) as Stephan proposed or you can use delayed expansion and set your statement into variable:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p carga= ¿Carga inicial o carga diaria?

set "statement=sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.SP_OFB_INF_PSN @VALOR = 1, @FECHA=''" -S (local) -d bd_ofb -o OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt"

if "%carga%"=="c" (
   !statement!
)
```